# new saxon error after upgrade - bad parent pointer in expression

Tags: saxon

I just upgraded from 9.4.0.6 to 9.8.0.8 and I'm getting an error now that didn't occur before. From other threads on this topic I assume this is related to internal optimizations and is more of a glitch than an error.

Here is the error message:

*** Bad parent pointer found in expression root / data / vineland2COM at file:/C:/some-file.xsl#17 ***

Here is the call that triggers it:

```
        <xsl:call-template name="common:stats.median">
           <xsl:with-param name="values" select="(/data/vineland2COM,
                    /data/vineland2DLS, 
                    /data/vineland2SOC,
                    /data/vineland2MOT)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
```

The output seems OK, which makes sense as explained in posts like: https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/6838?r=6841#message-6841 and https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2555

The same error repeats for every item in the sequence.

Is this something I can safely ignore? I can provide more detail if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the problem was present in earlier releases but we didn't notice it or report it.

Ideally we'd like you to put together a repro and report it to Saxonica so that we can fix it. The right place for that is saxonica.plan.io.

The error means we have found a corruption in an internal data structure, usually as a result of an incorrect tree rewrite during optimization. Much of the time we can recover after such an error and it causes no adverse effects; but occasionally it may lead to a fatal crash at run-time or even to incorrect results. So we'd like to know about it and to fix it.

Optimizations are looking for patterns of constructs in the code, sometimes quite complex patterns, and unfortunately the smarter you try and be with this, the more likely you are to overlook some edge cases. An additional problem is that every optimization you add doubles the number of test cases you need (and that's why these bugs slip through our testing).

Comment: Thanks for following this up on the Saxonica support site, where we were able to track it down: see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3691